# Nodejs + Express: How to terminate a response without providing a status code

Tags: node.js, http, express

Is it possible to terminate a response without providing any status code at all?

I have tried **res.end()** but it always returns **200 OK**.

The client has requested this behavior for security of their web application.

Comment: This may not be an issue with Node.js and Express, but with TCP/IP protocol. A TCP connection always sends a response, whereas a UDP/IP connection just sends data and does not wait for a response.

Comment: An HTTP response always has a status code. The only other option would be to terminate the connection without sending anything at all, though I fail to see the point. Just return an appropriate error code (probably a 40x error code) whenever necessary.

Comment: I suspected that this would be the answer and I really appreciate your knowledgeable responses.